# How to clear the cached statusCode in net request electronjs?

Tags: javascript, caching, electron

In my app, I use `net.request(url)`. I need to get the statusCode to display the right page e.g if the statusCode is 404, I want redirect to `not-found.html̀`.

Unfortunately, there is a problem with a cache somewhere :

1. Firstly, when the statusCode is 404, the app redirects to the 404 url template. It's ok.
2. Then, when I repair the page, I have a statusCode 200, the app redirects to the right page url. It's ok.
3. But when I broke my page again (it should be 404 not found), I get a statusCode 200 !

How to clear the app or this request?

my code:

```js
const request = net.request(url);
request.on("response", (response) => {
  // console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
  // console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
  response.on("data", (chunk) => {});
  response.on("end", () => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      win1.loadURL(url, { extraHeaders: "pragma: no-cache\n" });
      win1.show();
    } else {
      let url = `file://${__dirname}/not-found.html`;
      win1.loadURL(url, { extraHeaders: "pragma: no-cache\n" });
      win1.show();
    }
  });
});
request.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable disk cache.

When you start the application, add the `--disable-http-cache` parameter as explained [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/891#issuecomment-68786940) :

`electron . --disable-http-cache`